# Transpose $D^tf$ of operator derivation $D\in L(V,V)$ applied to a function $f$ which is the integral of $p\in V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transpose

I have to determine the transpose $D^tf$ of linear transformation $D\in L(V,V)$, where $V=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, for $a, b, \in \mathbb{R}$,  $f\in V^{*}$ defined by:

$$f(p)=\int_a^bp(x)dx.$$

Since the $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n+\ldots$ and $D(p)=a_1+2a_2x^1+\ldots+na_nx^{n-1}+\ldots$ I try to do by definition of $D^tf(p(x))=f(D(p))=\int_a^bD(p(x))dx=\int_a^b(a_1+2a_2x^1+\ldots+na_nx^{n-1}+\ldots)dx.$

My question is:

1- This interpretation already response the question, or is necessary desenvolve the calculus of integral?

2- For example, Do I need present the following development?$\int_a^b(a_1+2a_2x^1+\ldots+na_nx^{n-1}+\ldots)dx=a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^{n}+\ldots|_a^b=a_1(b-a)+a_2(b^2-a^2)+\ldots+a_n(b^n-a^n)+\ldots=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(b^i-a^i).$

Comment: Your definition of $D$ is strange. Do you mean to say that $D(p) = \frac{dp}{dx}$? That is, did you mean to write
$$
D(p) = a_1 + 2a_2 x^1 + \cdots + na_n x^{\color{red}{n-1}}?
$$

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$? If $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ denotes a space of polynomials, then there should be no infinite sums

Comment: If my assumptions about the question are correct, then the answer that you *should* arrive at is
$$
(D^tf)(p) = p(b) - p(a),
$$
which can be deduced from the result of your development (if $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is meant to denote the space of power series).

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question, thanks. And yes, $V=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Let me see, if I understand. We can conclude that $(D^tf)(p)=p(b)-p(a)$because the integral of the derivative of a function is the function itself. Perfect!

Comment: I understand that $V = \mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, but I don't understand what $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is supposed to mean

Comment: $V=\mathcal{P}({\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of polynomials of infinity base.